# Magento, Prices wrong on Cart

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart

I'm new to Magento and now I'm working on Magento Website, When adding a Simple product after adding a Confiurable product , the simple product displays the price of the Configurable product that added earlier ..

Answer (score 0):

The price you set the child product to is actually how much extra the price will be when that option is selected. I usually set the price of the configurable, parent product to that which I'd like the options to be then have the simple, child product set to 0.00 (unless the option increases or decreases the value)